# EF Loading Related Entities in Extension Methods

Tags: entity-framework, linq

With the below 1 to many relationship setup:

```
public partial class Folder
{
    public Folder()
    {
        Files = new HashSet<File>();
    }
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public partial class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext: DbContext
{
    ...
    public virtual DbSet<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>(entity =>
        {
            ...
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<File>(entity =>
        {
            ...
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Folder)
                  .WithMany(e => e.Files)
                  .HasForeignKey(e => e.FolderId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                  .HasConstraintName("...");
        });
    }
}

public SomeReturnType AFunction(IQueryable<Folder> folders) =>
    folders.GroupJoin(
        ...,
        (folder, other) => new
        {
            folder,
            something = folder.Files.Any(...)
        });
```

With `AFunction`, the related `Files` are loaded for `folder.Files.Any()`. But if I do the below:

```
public static class FolderExtensions
{
    public static SomeReturnType BFunction(this Folder folder) =>
        folder.Files.Any(...);
}

public SomeReturnType AFunction(IQueryable<Folder> folders) =>
        folders.GroupJoin(
            ...,
            (folder, other) => new
            {
                folder,
                something = folder.BFunction()
            });
```

`BFunction` will not load the related `Files`. Any ideas to get around this problem?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198227/10646316). Main problem that EF cannot translate compiled method to the SQL and you have to inject ExpresionTree. Also not that EFC has bad support for [GroupJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64389422/10646316)

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv and NetMage, thank you guys. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

To explain what happens let's first reduce the query to the essentials:

```cs
folders.Select(folder => new
    {
        folder,
        something = folder.BFunction()
    });
```

The problem here is that the `BFunction` method is executed client-side. That is, the part `IQueryable<Folder> folders` is first materialized into memory (*client-side*) and then the *projection* (`new { ... }`) is applied to the materialized result. This is something EF core does if anything in the final projection (and only in the final projection) can't be translated into SQL. Since `Files` are not `Include`-ed and no lazy loading occurs, the materialized folders don't have files and `BFunction` evaluates to `false`.

EF doesn't try to expand CLR functions into expression trees itself. In this case it would be possible, but often it won't be. At any rate, EF doesn't even try.

You have to do the expansion yourself:

```cs
folders.Select(folder => new
    {
        folder,
        something = folder.Files.Any()
    });
```

Including the files would also work, but of course that's more expensive:

```cs
folders
    .Include(f => f.Files)
    .Select(folder => new
    {
        folder,
        something = folder.BFunction()
    });
```

Side-note: the `GroupJoin` in this form is presently not supported by EF core (6.0).